# How do I allow non sysadmin accounts the ability to create/query linked servers in SQL Sever 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I want to allow a non-admin account the ability to query a linked server.

If I create a linked server with the following under a sysadmin account like below.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LINKEDSERVER', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'IhOLEDB.iHistorian', @datasrc=N'linkedservername'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LINKEDSERVER',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER, 'SELECT  * FROM ihTags')` from a sysadmin account (no matter what account it is), it works.

If I run the query from a non-sysadmin account I get the following error.

> `Msg 7416, Level 16, State 2, Line 2` 
>    `Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.`

Comment: Wrap those commands in a stored procedure and sign it. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/signing-stored-procedures-in-sql-server) and [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-2017). [This](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) may also be useful.

Comment: @AaronBertrand same issue "Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists." My SP creates the LinkedServer, however when I run a query like above it gives the error message.

Comment: You need to create a stored procedure that runs the select command(s), sign it, and have your users call that. It doesn't matter who **created** the linked server, it matters who is trying to query from it...

Comment: @AaronBertrand But people need to be able to run any query they want, not just a single static query. The only option I can think of is allowing the user to pass in an entire query to the SP such as the entire string "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER, 'SELECT  * FROM ihTags')" but that seems extremely hacky. Is there not another way?

Comment: If you want them to run any arbitrary query against a linked server, then yes either you need to execute dynamic SQL from within your signed procedure (they only need to pass the `SELECT * FROM ihTags` bit if you know this will always be run against `LINKEDSERVER`), or you'll have to give them appropriate permissions against the linked server. This doesn't mean `sysadmin` but it's obviously more than they've got now, and I'm not sure if you're using Windows credentials or not but you'll need to add additional logins with the right permissions using `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand We are not using Windows credentials. We were adding a new account that has access to this one particular DB (read only if possible) and being able to write arbitrary queries against the linked servers. I tried giving this account "Alter any linked server" and "Alter any login" from what I read online but that still didn't work. What permissions do I need to give this account to let it run the arbitrary queries on the linked server?

Comment: The login you create on SQL Server has to somehow map to a login on the other server. I apologize, I have absolutely no idea what an `ihOLEDB.iHistorian` provider is, so I don't know how to give any further guidance. Have you checked with their documentation or support team to see how they recommend reading from SQL Server? On SQL Server you would create the same SQL auth login/password on the linked server, give them the appropriate permissions *there*, and then set up the linked server login on the local server with the right values for `@rmtuser` and `@rmtpassword`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The account that the `sysadmin` is using to run the query on the linked server has no login credentials with just read access to the linked server (see the original post EXEC). Doing this with an account on the MSSQL with `sysadmin` the query works. Performing the same query with an account without `sysadmin` doesn't work.

Comment: I believe I understand your current situation. Forget about your local `sysadmin` accounts. Does this `iHistorian` system support logins/users, can you create one there with the correct read only access you want, and can you then create a local linked server login that uses **those credentials** for `@rmtuser`/`@rmtpassword`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84296/discussion-between-kevin-vasko-and-aaron-bertrand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Article: [Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/03/10/access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-no-login-mapping-exists/)

Need to specify `User ID` in the provider string if `Non-SYSAdmin` accounts are used.

Example:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'MyLinkServerName',
    @provider = N'SQLNCLI',
    @srvproduct = 'SQLNCLI',
    @provstr = N'SERVER=MyServerName\MyInstanceName;User ID=myUser'
```

Comment: Thanks. So providing a username `EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LINKEDSERVER',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=N'MyLocalAccountRO',@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL` seems to have gotten past that error message. However, now I'm getting a different error message. `Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "IhOLEDB.iHistorian" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER".` But this seems to be a different problem and I'll create a different question about it.